# Android : How do you get activities to talk with a service smoothly

Tags: android, service, android-livedata, aidl

I am fairly new to Android and java so, bear with me.

I am working on an app that's basically a VOIP app.
The design is quite simple :

- A "Foreground" service : it handles audio, connectivity, etc ...
- A few repositories that store the data (mostly they are MutableLiveData)
- A few ViewModels that basically just act as middle men (nothing much done in there)
- Activities that use the ViewModels to display data and interact with the service.

It's all fine but I have recently been notified that I had to allow other apps to interact with the service.

I've look around a bit and it seems to me I should use an AIDL interface to achieve that.
I managed - sweating a bit - to put the AIDL interface in place.

I have quite a lot of data and data types and it seems to me like this would be a very tedious work to have to add a getter for every data AND a callback for each of them so I can be notified if a change occurs.

So basically I have two questions :

- How would you have done this - what would be the best solution ?
- Considering I have quite a lot of time and code invested in my lame solution, what would be the best compromise so the solution is not too ugly and the implementation doesn't make me trash all my code ?

Thanks for your time and input !

P.S. My minSdkVersion is 22 and I'm coding with java.

Comment: What was the interface between existing foreground service and UI before you added the AIDL ? Is your data already Parcelable ?

Comment: The background service and the UI share the same objects (the repositories) and the viewModels' liveDatas changes kind of act as events.
My objects are not yet parcelable.